# Micronaut: Authentication Principal generated into request body

Tags: swagger, openapi, micronaut

I'm trying to generate client code with swagger-codegen from a Micronaut server. The problem arises with authenticated POST and PUT routes (it works fine for GET an DELETE).

When I have a method like this in a controller:

```
@Override
@Post("/")
public Single<? extends HttpResponse> updateStatus(Authentication authentication, GameReference gameReference) {
    // ...
}
```

The resulting swagger for that method looks like this:

```
post:
  tags:
  - /presence
  description: Updates status
  operationId: updateStatus
  parameters: []
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            authentication:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Authentication'
            gameReference:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/GameReference'
    required: true
  responses:
    default:
      description: HTTP 204 for successful updates.
      content:
        application/json: {}
```

So the Authentication Principal has been built into the request body and in generated client code the parameters to that method would be an object with both Authentication and GameReference.

What I have tried to work around this problem:

- Add @Parameter(hidden = true) before Authentication parameter. Did not change anything.
- Playing around with swagger annotations for authentication, like @SecuritySchema and @SecurityDefention. Authentication Principle still gets generated into the swagger yaml.

Is this a bug in Micronauts Swagger implementation or is there a way to work-around this? Note that this works well for GET and DELETE. There the Authentication Principle is ignored.

Comment: Opened a issue with Micronaut: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1155

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was accepted as a bug by the Micronaut team:
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1155